# Micropost API format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have been following this tutorial:https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts. My question is, how would I turn my microposts into a readable json format for my API? Here is my Micropost controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

The only field for the micropost is the content field. How would I show this as json in my api? Also here is my Users controller that handles showing the micropost:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
      end
end
```

I understand I need to create the api and version folders, but I do not know how I would format the micropost response into json. I was able to do it for my users, but I am struggling with the microposts. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to respond with `JSON`, you might need to configure your controllers to respond to this format. One way to do it is by calling `respond_to`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json
end
```

Checkout Rails documentation for more details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html

Comment: Would I have to create a show method in the micropost to display on a seperate page in the api?